# Delete the entire table rendered from different pages using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am having a table  like:

```
 <table id="toc" class="toc" border="1" summary="Contents">
 </table>
```

in many pages .. All these pages are rendered in a single page.
when I apply the Javascript to delete that using on load. Only one table is deleted and not the others.

I am trying to delete the  tables in all the rendering pages using Javascript. How to do this?

Edit :
I myself found the solution

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onLoad = load(); 
  function load(){var tbl = document.getElementById('toc'); 
   if(tbl) tbl.parentNode.removeChild(tbl);} 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Really want to delete the table altogether?**

```
var elem = documenet.getElementById('toc');

if (typeof elem != 'undefined')
{
  elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

You could also **hide** the table rather than deleting it.

```
var elem = documenet.getElementById('toc');
elem.style.display = 'none';
```

If you need it later, you could simply do:

```
var elem = documenet.getElementById('toc');
elem.style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: I think he's better off hiding it via a style

Comment: @Pierreten: Yes, it was important to post that. Thanks

Comment: Only in somecases the table gets removed. but not all the times .. Y so ??

Comment: This solution works for me but I wonder no one mentioned spelling mistake for documenet instead of correct one document.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a rough sample

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function removeTable(id)
    {
        var tbl = document.getElementById(id);
        if(tbl) tbl.parentNode.removeChild(tbl);
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="toc" class="toc" border="1" summary="Contents">
    <tr><td>This table is going</td></tr>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="removeTable('toc');" value="Remove!" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function deleteTable(){
    document.getElementById('div_table').innerHTML="TABLE DELETED"
  }
</script>

<div id="div_table">

 <table id="toc" class="toc" border="1" summary="Contents">
 </table>
</div>
<input type="button" onClick="deleteTable()">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var tbl = document.getElementById(id);
tbl.remove();
```

Comment: remove() is not a function it says: